# If $\sum a_n$ converges then for which $p$ does $\sum \sqrt{a_n}/n^p$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I show that for any sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $p>\frac12$, we have that
$$\sum_n \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$$ converges if $$\sum_n a_n$$ converges?

Comment: You should specify that all $a_n\ge 0.$

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that $a_n\geq0$ since you enter complex analysis otherwise.

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for all $N\in\mathbb N$:

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}\right)^2\le\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{2p}}.$$

The right-hand side is uniformly bounded as the sum of the reciprocals of $n^{2p}$ converges for $p>\frac12$ and since the sum of the $a_n$ is convergent.

By monotone convergence Theorem, we reach the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

$a_n \ge 0$;

AM-GM:

$\small{b_n:=a_n +\dfrac{1}{n^{2p}} \ge 2\dfrac {√a_n}{n^p}\ge \dfrac{√a_n}{n^p} \ge 0;}$

$\sum b_n$ converges for $p>1/2$.

By comparison test $\sum \dfrac{√a_n}{n^p}$ converges.