# Rudin Exercise 3.7

Tags: analysis

The problem I'm working on is: Prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges, $\sum {\sqrt a_n \over n} $ converges given that $a_n \ge 0$. It seems like the way most people have solved this is by splitting it up into two sums using Cauchy's inequality. Instead, can I do this problem directly using the comparison test? We know that $\sum a_n$ converges, and since we are taking the square root and dividing by n, each term is just  getting smaller. Isn't this enough to conclude that $\sum {\sqrt a_n \over n} $ converges by the comparison test?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect because $\sqrt x> x$ whenever $0<x<1$

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429873

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming it had to be an integer for some reason

Comment: If all $a_n$ are non-negative integers then the sequence is quite boring because all but finitely many $a_n$ would have to be $0$ for the sum to converge.